# Node-postgres pool.connect becomes unresponsive

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, rest, freeze

Hiii,
Recently my elastic beanstalk server have started to become unresponsive and return's 504 gateway timeout. I suspect that my pool.connect is becoming unresponsive and there are no logs reporting error while connecting to pool but it stucks at connecting. My other controllers with no database query works fine.
This goes away when I restart the server but after some time same thing happens.

I making requests this way-
1) database.js

```
const pg = require("pg")
// setting timestamp for the postgres.
pg.types.setTypeParser(1184, function(stringValue)
{
    console.log(stringValue)
    return new Date(Date.parse(Date.parse(stringValue + "+0000")))
})

// configuration for postres for connecting.
const pgConfig = {
    user: "USER",
    database: "DATABASE",
    password: "1234",
    port: 5432
}
const pool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig)
module.exports = pool
```

2) somecontroller.js

```
const db = require("../database/database")
const constant = require("../utility/constant")

module.exports = function(req, res)
{

    db.connect(function(err, client, done)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            done()
            console.log(constant.error.db.CONNECT_CONSOLE, err)
            return res.send({status: constant.status.ERROR, code: constant.error.db.CONNECT})
        }

        client.query("QUERY", [UID])
        .then(result => 
        {
            // Processing this queries and Some other query.....
        })
        .catch(err => 
        {
            console.log(constant.error.db.QUERY_CONSOLE, err)
            res.send({status: constant.status.ERROR, code: constant.error.db.QUERY})
        })

        done()
    })
}
```

My every controller works in similar fashion.

Thanks,

Comment: When database pools become unresponsive, it's typically caused by connections not being return into the pool or because queries taking a lot of time and the pool size being too small (so at some point, all connections are waiting for a query to finish and new requests are piling up).

Comment: @robertklep should i increase pool size??

Comment: I'm just providing some possible reasons why the connections may be timing out. I don't run your app so can't tell specifically which reason (if any) is causing your specific problems. You need to debug your app yourself and rule out things.

Comment: @robertklep i found the issue. It was a controller which was not releasing client properly. I still increased the pool size. Thanks for helping though.